# How do I get my button group <div> to stick to the bottom of my navbar?

Tags: html, css, button

As you can see, the containter div is set to `position: relative` and the position of the `btn-group` itself is `absolute` but it is still sicking to the top of the navbar div.

```css
.btn-group button{
    background-color: #FFB48F;
    color: #2D283E;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100px;
 height: 70%;
 border: none;
 border-left: 1px solid #2D283E;
 border-right: 1px solid #2D283E;
 float: left;
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
 border-top-left-radius: none;
}
.btn-group button:not(:first-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
 border-top-left-radius: none;
}
/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
    color: #FFB48F;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 247);
}
.btn-group button:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

/* NEW STUFF HERE */

.topnav{
 background-color: #2D283E;
 color: rgb(91, 27, 143);
    text-decoration: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #FFB48F; 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 2;
 clear:both;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.titlebox{
 background-color: #FFB48F;
 margin-left: 20px;
 color: #2D283E;
 width: 13%;
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 height: 70%;
 float: left;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 3px;
 padding-top: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.titlebox h1{
 font-size: 16px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px; /* this stops divs from clipping navbar */
}
.row{
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<div class="topnav">
 <div class="titlebox"><h1>title 0.1 beta</h1></div>
  <div style="height: 100%; position: relative;">
 <div class="btn-group" style="height: 100%; right:0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;">
  <button href="#">Title</button>
  <button href="#">Admin</button>
  <button href="#">Logout</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought the issue might be with one of the containers, my bad.

Comment: Done - thanks mate.

Comment: Using position absolute is not the correct way to do it, you can do it simpler only with basic margin property. My answer is waiting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, short & clean. You should use margin-top for you elements inside your bar.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
  font-family: serif;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2D283E;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffb48f;
}

div#title-box, nav {
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-top: 15px;
}

div#title-box {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div#title-box > h1, nav > button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;  
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: #ffb48f;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 25px;  
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
}

nav > button {
  border: none;
}

nav > button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #ffb48f;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="title-box">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <button href="#">MenuR 1</button>
    <button href="#">MenuR 2</button>
    <button href="#">MenuR 3</button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your height:100%; style is interfering with the style you want. for buttons to have some breathing space give some padding to it. Changes are made to class styles ".btn-group button {"

```css
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #FFB48F;
  color: #2D283E;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70%;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #2D283E;
  border-right: 1px solid #2D283E;
  float: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  border-top-left-radius: none;
}

.btn-group button:not(:first-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  border-top-left-radius: none;
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group button:hover {
  color: #FFB48F;
  background-color: rgb(243, 244, 247);
}

.btn-group button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* NEW STUFF HERE */

.topnav {
  background-color: #2D283E;
  color: rgb(91, 27, 143);
  text-decoration: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFB48F;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  clear: both;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.titlebox {
  background-color: #FFB48F;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #2D283E;
  width: 13%;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.titlebox h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  /* this stops divs from clipping navbar */
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="titlebox">
      <h1>title 0.1 beta</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div class="btn-group" style="right:0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;">
        <button href="#">Title</button>
        <button href="#">Admin</button>
        <button href="#">Logout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yay! Thanks mate.

Comment: Is there a way I can make them extend exactly 70% the height of the navbar the same way I have the the titlebox? edit - I ended up setting container div to height 70% and `btn-group{height: 100%}` - seems to have worked.

Comment: Using position absolute for this purpose is not recommended at all.